# What is the difference between Cassandra vs Oracle Coherence?

Tags: oracle, cassandra, oracle-coherence

Assume that Oracle Coherence is free :)

Which one do you prefer?

What are the architectural and feature capability differences between Oracle Coherence(Tangosol) and Cassandra?

Best Regards

Comment: Found something more to compare http://bhavin.directi.com/tag/cassandra/ or look at http://www.slideshare.net/rbadaro/writing-scalable-software-in-java. I think it depends on the requirements.

Answer (score 14):

Oracle Coherence is a pure in-memory cache which can be distributed across nodes. Depending on its configuration it can have strong consistency, or eventual consistency for inserts and updates. Coherence is object based - consistent data model.
Since you buy Coherence from oracle - you can get commercial support, from oracle.

Cassandra is a bigtable data store that is distributed across nodes. No single point of failure. It uses some caching to improve performance before committing the data to disk in its implementation of bigTable. Cassandra requires some structure in its tuple (key/value/timestamp) but otherwise can support flexible data structures.

Preferences should be determined by your use case. They are both pretty cool in their own right.

You might also want to check out 
 - Terracotta in the in-memory space
 - CouchDB and HBase as other players in the big table space.

Comment: Well the big difference is that Coherence is also a compute offload engine - your client sends code *into* the cache for execution there. That is why Oracle refer to it as a "grid" rather than just a "cache".

Comment: I should point out that Coherence can also be configured as "no single point of failure", having a primary and backup copy of each data element across nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Lets not forget Gemfire from Gemstone Systems, now owned by VMware (http://www.vmware.com/products/vfabric-gemfire/overview.html).  Gemfire is an in memory distributed data fabric similar to Coherence and Terracotta but different in certain key ways.  Each one has their pro's and cons but Gemfire is getting more support in a Spring sub project lately called spring-gemfire.

Answer (score 0):

Both are NoSQL Databases. Currently there are 3 types of NoSQL databases that exists - Key Value Store, Tabular and Document Oriented. Coherence is a key value store, Cassandra is more like a tabular and MongoDB is a Document Oriented nosql db.